# Using Request Response Filter in a multi-module springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-filters, multi-module

I have created a multi-module application with 3 modules in it (one main and two other modules). I have created a custom request response filter in all the three modules with ***same name***.

Now when I am triggering an endpoint present in one module, the request is getting filtered randomly through any of the three filters and hence getting unexpected response each time.

Can someone please help me with this if they have encountered this earlier as I am not getting slight clue why this is happening?

Also, if possible please share detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't duplicate them.

Every implementation of `javax.servlet.Filter` annotated as a @Component will be created and added to the filter pipeline by Spring

Comment: In fact, why would anyone put them the same name if they are different filters?

Comment: @prakhar - Did you understand this answer, please accept the answer. If not, please comment.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWilliams, I understood the answer and I was able to solve the issue that I was facing.